# Why getting getActionBar null in android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I want to get instance of action bar but getting the value null and because of that my whole program is not running.

My code where I have included this method is:

When my code jumps to line where action bar is needed it gives me null pointer exception

HomeTab.java:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

public class HomeTab extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    MyCustomAdapter myCustomAdapter;
    Context context=HomeTab.this;


    //ImageView menuimage;

    String optionName[]=new String[] {"Alerts","Events","Newsletters","News","Parent Info","Logins","Parent Teacher Interviews","Flexi School LunchOrder","Contact US","Kool Content"};

    //int image[]=new int[] {R.drawable.alert_small_icon,R.drawable.events,R.drawable.newsletter,R.drawable.newsletter,R.drawable.arrow_24,R.drawable.arrow_24,R.drawable.arrow_24,R.drawable.arrow_24,R.drawable.arrow_24,R.drawable.arrow_24};
    int imageArrow[]=new int[]{R.drawable.right_arrow};

    ArrayList<ListModel> mylist=new ArrayList<ListModel>();

    // test for sliding drawer
    /*
    String[] menu;
    DrawerLayout dLayout;
    ListView dList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;*/


    /*
     * code from leftslide
     * 
     */
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    public ListView DrawerList;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
 // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    LayoutInflater inflater=null;



    // code upto left slide

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.list_view_layout);

        //menuimage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menuimage);


        //new code below
        /*menuimage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menuimage);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu);

        menu = new String[]{"Home","Android","Windows","Linux","Raspberry Pi","WordPress","Videos","Contact Us"};
        dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        dList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);*/

        //new above

        ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        getDatainList();

        listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(context, mylist));

        listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);



        inflater=(LayoutInflater)HomeTab.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View vi=inflater.inflate(com.example.testlist.R.layout.sliding_activity_main, null);


        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(com.example.testlist.R.array.nav_drawer_items);

         //nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(com.example.testlist.R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        DrawerList = (ListView) vi.findViewById(R.id.left_draw);


        DrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
//               displayView(position);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi", 300).show();

            }
        }); 



        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<com.ctpl.skoolbag.leftslide.NavDrawerItem>();



        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new com.ctpl.skoolbag.leftslide.NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0],navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new com.ctpl.skoolbag.leftslide.NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1],navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new com.ctpl.skoolbag.leftslide.NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2],navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new com.ctpl.skoolbag.leftslide.NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3],navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new com.ctpl.skoolbag.leftslide.NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4],navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new com.ctpl.skoolbag.leftslide.NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5],navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new com.ctpl.skoolbag.leftslide.NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6],navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new com.ctpl.skoolbag.leftslide.NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7],navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new com.ctpl.skoolbag.leftslide.NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);

        DrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.cat, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.left_slide, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(DrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }



    private void getDatainList() 
    {

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)

        {
            ListModel li=new ListModel();
            li.setOptionName(optionName[i]);
        //  li.setImage(image[i]);
            li.setImageArrow(R.drawable.arrow);

            mylist.add(li);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) 
    {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:

            Intent call_AlertWebService=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AlertActivityFromService.class);
            startActivity(call_AlertWebService);

            break;

        case 1:

            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EventsFromWebService.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case 2:

            Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewslettersActivityFromService.class);
            startActivity(in);
            break;

        case 3:
            Intent inn=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewsFromService.class);
            startActivity(inn);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }


    }



/**
* Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
* */

private void displayView(int position) {
// update the main content by replacing fragments
android.app.Fragment fragment = null;
switch (position) {
case 0:
    fragment = new HomeFragment();
    break;
/*case 1:
    fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
    break;
case 2:
    fragment = new PhotosFragment();
    break;
case 3:
    fragment = new CommunityFragment();
    break;
case 4:
    fragment = new PagesFragment();
    break;
case 5:
    fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
    break;
*/
default:
    break;
}

if (fragment != null) {
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(com.example.testlist.R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    DrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    DrawerList.setSelection(position);
    setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerList);
} else {
    // error in creating fragment
    Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
}
}



}
```

Comment: You haven't explained *where* you're getting the problem, and you've posted nearly 400 lines of code, including large commented-out sections. You should reduce your code so that it's complete but does nothing *except* demonstrate the problem. Just the minimum required to do that. You may well find that in trimming your code to that minimum demonstration, you find the problem yourself.

Comment: did you use any style in your code like noTitleBar?

Comment: did you need to post that massive code file including import statements?

Comment: And a search for `getActionBar null` in Stack Overflow shows *lots* of duplicates.

Comment: in oncreate method() where I am using getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Comment: i have not used any style like notitle bar

Comment: first atleast see my code that why I am getting Action bar null because I am using inflater to load second xml

Answer (score -1):

once check your minSdkVersion.

change to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
```

Comment: checked it.. but still facing same